# Failed to resolve: lib

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, lib

I think I lost a libriry...!
I tried all "stackoverflow" solutions without good results!

ERROR: Failed to resolve: lib
Affected Modules: app

I didn't use this code source for a while...! after I open it, I got this error!

> This is my full gradle file: app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Splendid.Braid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 25
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.lsjwzh.RecyclerViewPager:lib:v1.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:Side-Menu.Android:1.0.1'
    implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'com.fivehundredpx:blurringview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
    //implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':menu')
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bhargavms:DotLoader:1.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add to your project level build.gradle's allprojects block like this

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

from: https://github.com/bhargavms/DotLoader